# Wicket onsubmit information dialog

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, wicket

I am trying to have wicket display an information dialog after a save button is clicked which invokes an onsubmit that has no access to AjaxRequestTarget target. Here is code snippet

```
if (trainingmode() && !recordDecision.equalsIgnoreCase("Primary")) {               
    if (trainingEvalService.compareDecisions(recordDecision, recordSet.getRecordSetId())) {                
        System.out.println("Validity matchesMaserati: " + trainingEvalService.getTrainingEval().getActual_validity_decision_comment());
        // Dialog associated with save button
        dialog = new MessageDialog("dialog", "Notice", "Decision Matches " + trainingEvalService.getTrainingEval().getActual_validity_decision_comment() , DialogButtons.OK_CANCEL, DialogIcon.WARN) {
            public void onClose(AjaxRequestTarget target, DialogButton button) {
            }
        }; 

        dialog.open(target) // breaks here without reference to AjaxTarget           
    } else {                 
    }                
}
```

How can I get a reference to the current AjaxRequestTarget?

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: I assume you're looking for RequestCycle.get().find(AjaxRequestTarget.class)

Comment: @svenmeir yes you are close i tried to do this below but got an error   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException                                                        dialog = new MessageDialog("dialog", "Notice", "Decision Matches " + trainingEvalService.getTrainingEval().getActual_validity_decision_comment() , DialogButtons.OK_CANCEL, DialogIcon.WARN) {
              public void onClose(AjaxRequestTarget target, DialogButton button) {
              }
          }; 
          dialog.open( RequestCycle.get().find(AjaxRequestTarget.class));

Answer (score 0):

Two ways :

1. If you are doing the form submit through a link, then you can add a SimpleAttributeModifire to it.

**Example :**

```
yourLink.add(new SimpleAttributeModifier("onclick","alert('information')"));
```

This ll display a javascript info, on which you can show the information.

**Note :**
If you are not submitting from link, then you can do that by putting the submit code in the onSubmit() of a SubmitLink.

2. You can also use ModalWidow for this, but for that you ll need Ajax submit.
   You can use AjaxSubmitLink for that.
   You can find ModalWindow code from here:
   http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples-6.0.x/ajax/modal-window;jsessionid=2E08EC28B0C0A1AD3F8399628F048003?0